# Postgres SQL query inconsistency

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

How is it possible to get a different result (0 rows vs 272 rows) when running SELECT * vs COUNT(*) with the same query in Postgres 12 on Linux? The database is not changing. I tried vacuuming and restarting the Postgres server. I am manually trying to clean up a corrupted database by removing some references to an unimportant table that didn't get properly deleted and keeps throwing errors. Yes, I backed up all the data first.

I am mostly wondering if this is a bug, or I am misunderstanding how to use SQL. Also note that adding an AND condition increases the number of results for COUNT, which does not make sense to me.

Psql console dump:

```
postgres=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_attribute WHERE pg_attribute.attrelid >= 2128137 AND pg_attribute.attrelid <= 2132360;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_attribute WHERE pg_attribute.attrelid >= 2128137 AND pg_attribute.attrelid <= 2132360 AND pg_attribute.attname NOT ILIKE '%pg.dropped%';
 count 
-------
   272
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_attribute WHERE pg_attribute.attrelid >= 2128137 AND pg_attribute.attrelid <= 2132360 AND pg_attribute.attname NOT ILIKE '%pg.dropped%';
 count 
-------
   272
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_attribute WHERE pg_attribute.attrelid >= 2128137 AND pg_attribute.attrelid <= 2132360 AND pg_attribute.attname NOT ILIKE '%pg.dropped%';
(returns 0 rows in editor)
```

Comment: What are the plans for the queries?  "I am manually trying to clean up a corrupted database"  well, if your database is known to be corrupted, that seems like a sufficient explanation for pretty much any observation.

Comment: The plan is to replace the SELECT * with a DELETE, to remove references to attributes that should have been deleted (which also deletes 0 results right now). All of the other tables in the database seems to be working fine, so I've held out hope it's a recoverable bug. The original Postgres bug/error message which prevents creating a new table of the same name is this: "ERROR:  catalog is missing 16 attribute(s) for relid 2128167"

Answer (score 1):

It is “normal” for queries on a corrupted database to return wrong results.

Rather than trying to fix the corruption (where you can never be certain that there may not be more corruption be lurking somewhere), `pg_dump` the database and restore it to a **newly created cluster on different hardware**. If you are lucky, that will work, and you are fine.

Catalog corruption is the nastiest kind. If the above doesn't work, seek professional help. If you don't know what a query plan is, you won't be able to do that yourself (no insult intended).